# Why would we use a pointer in an NSInteger but not in an NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsnumber, nsinteger

I have an NSInteger that doesn't use a pointer and an NSNumber that does use a pointer. Can someone explain to me why this is the case? All my teacher said was the NSInteger is being used as a type alias but I'm not familiar with that either yet.

This question asked a direct question asking for the reason there was no pointer in NSInteger; not asking for all the differences.

[image]

Comment: I think you can find the answer here (with even more information): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285098/whats-the-difference-between-nsnumber-and-nsinteger

Comment: thank you for the wonderful resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that Objective-C is C. Thus:

- An NSInteger is a *scalar*, a built-in C data type (an integer). [The actual size of this integer depends on the architecture, 32-bit vs. 64-bit. But it is still some form of C integer.]
- An NSNumber is an *object*; Objective-C object references are represented as C pointers.

Comment: Okay perfect. Got it...... because pointers can only be used on objects and not on C data types.

Comment: Pointers _can_ be used on C data types. You can have a pointer-to-int. But you don't have one _here_, nor do you need one.

Comment: Might help you to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#_pointers

Comment: okay wonderful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: loving the detail in the book. great presentation.