# Why is MySQL seeing 1000.00 as a smaller number than 34.00?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 products, one is a thousand dollars so for it's price I inserted into the database:

1000.00

and nother thats 34 dollars so I inserted:

34.00

But when I sort the products in order by price (low to high) the $1,000 product comes before the $34 one, why?

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price ASC;
```

### EDIT

It's a varchar field. I would have used int but I need the decimal to be accepted.

If I turn it to int, is there any way I can convert something like this:

10000

to a more user friendly form when display to the user like:

$10,000

I am using PHP for scripting by the way.

Comment: what is your price field like ? char ? double ?

Comment: Make it an int, in cents, not dollars.  Handle the decimal in the client.

Comment: If using version 5.03 or greater, consider the `DECIMAL` datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because strings are sorted lexicographically. You need to cast it to a number to be sorted numerically.

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL) ASC;
```

(It may be better to store the price as INTEGERs as multiple of cents (100000 and 3400), or use DECIMAL.)

---

Edit: You can use [`money_format` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) to convert a number to currency format. See http://www.ideone.com/VEcgy for an example.

Comment: that is a pretty nice question inst double more applicable for currency ?

Comment: @Prix: [ __No__ !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount/66678#66678)

Answer (score 3):

Lexically speaking, 1000.00 is less than 34.00.  What data type is price?

Answer (score 0):

You've stored price as an varchar, but indeed it is numeric ;)
Use DECIMAL(10,2) or DOUBLE(10,2) to store the price, both types preserve the point.

Comment: I actually prefer DECIMAL(10,4) as people like the IRS can specify sub 1 cent values (such as car mileage rebate rates)