# Suggest an optimised mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have table with user transactions.I need to select users who made total transactions more than  100 000 in a single day.Currently what I'm doing is gather all user ids and execute

```
SELECT sum ( amt ) as amt from users where date = date("Y-m-d") AND user_id=id;
```

for each id and checking weather the amt >  100k or not.

Since it's a large table, it's taking lot of time to execute.Can some one suggest an optimised query ?

Comment: `select user_id,sum(amt) as amount from table where date=date("Y-M-D") group by user_id having amount>100000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
SELECT sum ( amt ) as amt, user_id from users
where date = date("Y-m-d") 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING sum ( amt ) > 1;   ' not sure what Lakh is
```

Answer (score 1):

What about filtering the record 1st and then applying sum like below

```
select SUM(amt),user_id from (
SELECT  amt,user_id from users where user_id=id date = date("Y-m-d") 
)tmp 
group by user_id having sum(amt)>100000
```

Answer (score 1):

1. What datatype is amt?  If it's anything but a basic integral type (e.g. int, long, number, etc.) you should consider converting it.  Decimal types are faster than they used to be, but integral types are faster still.
2. Consider adding indexes on the date and user_id field, if you haven't already.
3. You can combine the aggregation and filtering in a single query...

   ```
   SELECT SUM(Amt) as amt 
   FROM users 
   WHERE date=date(...) 
     AND user_id=id 
   GROUP BY user_id
   HAVING amt > 1
   ```

Comment: `1)It's float`
`2)Will do`
`3)Ok`

Comment: For monetary amounts, you should definitely switch to a Decimal data type at least.  See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3768908/444013).  If you're trying to ultra-optimize your query, you should switch to an integral type (e.g. bigint) and do the decimal conversions in your display code.

Answer (score 1):

The only optimization that can be done in your query is by applying primary key on user_id column to speed up filtering.

As far as other answers posted which say to apply GROUP BY on filtered records, it won't have any effect as WHERE CLAUSE is executed first in SQL logical query processing phases.
[Check here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySql sub-queries to let MySql handle all the iterations. For example, you could structure your query like this:

```
select user_data.user_id, user_data.total_amt from 
(
    select sum(amt) as total_amt, user_id from users where date = date("Y-m-d") AND user_id=id
) as user_data
where user_data.total_amt > 100000;
```

Comment: this will execute ever slower than OPs sql. because u have wrapped OP's query in the inner query