# PHP version of Javascript Modulus operation

Tags: php, modulus

I'm looking for a PHP version for the Javascript modulus (%) operation. I need to get this for some mapping algorithms I'm trying to port to PHP. When I use PHP's bcmod, my results are off some.

Here's what I have so far.

```
public static function mod($operand_str, $modulus_res)
{
    $arg_arr = array();
    $arg_arr = func_get_args();

    $operand_str = strval($operand_str);
    $modulus_res = strval($modulus_res);

    $retain_scale_bool = (!isset($arg_arr[2]) || $arg_arr[2] == '') ? false: $arg_arr[2];

    //get decimal
    $decimal_arr = array();
    $decimal_arr = explode('.', $operand_str);

    switch(true)
    {
        case ($retain_scale_bool == true):
            $modulus_new_res = bcmod($operand_str, $modulus_res);
            $modulus_new_res = $modulus_new_res.'.'.$decimal_arr[1];
        break;

        default:
            $modulus_new_res = bcmod($operand_str, $modulus_res);
    }

    return $modulus_new_res;
}
```

Just as an example. Here are the results I get when I do 3.1432444 % 3:
With Javascript: 0.14324439999999994
With PHP: 0
With My Function: 0.1432444

I want to get the Javascript result with my function.

Can you help adjust my script. I'm no math wiz so I'm not going to be able to take this to the first principles of the modulus operation.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried fmod? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [fmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php), which works with floats:

```
fmod(3.1432444, 3);
```

Comment: my function already gives me the same result as fmod(). I want to get the result that I mentioned is returned by Javascript?!

Comment: @Chuck: I don't understand how the modulus in JS for `3.1432444 % 3` would give you 0.14324439999999994... Where is the 9999999994 bit coming from? If anything, it's the JS version that is giving you the wrong result, or the actual left operand is not 3.1432444.

Comment: @Netcoder: That's what I got. Maybe you can try it out yourself. Is the result wrong then?!

Comment: @Chuck See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966484/floating-point-numbers-and-javascript-modulus-operator) question and the answers.

Comment: @Netcoder: Thanks. I guess I'll stick with my function since javascript has errors.