# Rounding problems with calculate numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got the following problem when i'm counting in javascript.

```
var processAmount = parseFloat(166.98) - parseFloat(61.58);
```

The result is: `105.39999999999999`

Doesnt matter if I use `parseFloat()` or not.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What about `.toFixed(2)`?

Comment: solve what? We can only assume what expected output is since you haven't defined it

Comment: Yes `.toFixed(2)` works fine in this case. `var processAmount = parseFloat(parseFloat(166.98).toFixed(2) - parseFloat(61.58).toFixed(2)).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes floats numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Try this:

```
var processAmount = parseFloat(166.98) - parseFloat(61.58);
processAmount.toFixed(2);
```

FROM: [Javascript float subtract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027937/javascript-float-subtract)