# Javascript Math.cos and Math.sin are inaccurate. Is there any solution?

Tags: javascript, math

JavaScript Math trigonometrical methods return wrong results.

```js
alert(Math.sin(Math.PI));
// sin(180) in degrees should return 0, but above code doesn't
```

it doesn't return 0.

Maybe problem is with JavaScript decimal number precision. Is there any workaround to get correct results?

Comment: Is it acceptable to your side to round off the result? `1.2246467991473532e-16` is quite small and rounding it off will convert it to `0`. Well, JS's `Math` is not developed for high precision math :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point numbers and JavaScript modulus operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966484/floating-point-numbers-and-javascript-modulus-operator) and probably a couple hundred others.

Comment: woes of finite precision... (even though     `1-Math.pow(Math.cos(Math.PI),2) == 0`)

Comment: Maybe you should read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic": http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: just noticed this. Just nuts. You would think they could have friggin optimized `sin` to give the right answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's very, very close to zero, though.  (~ 10^-16)

And `alert(Math.sin(Math.PI/2))` does return `1`.

It's just one of things you have to be careful of when dealing with floating point arithmetic.  Rounding errors pop up all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

you can use

`Math.sin(Math.PI).toFixed(3) // "0.000"`

### Examples:

`const cos = (a) => Math.cos(Math.PI * a / 180);
cos(90) // 6.123233995736766e-17`

then you can use `.toFixed()`

`cos(90).toFixed(3) // "0.000"`

### Note

`.toFixed()` returns string, so you can parse it to float using `parseFloat()`

`parseFloat(cos(90).toFixed(3)) // 0.000`

Comment: OP's complaining about precision and your solution is to make it less precise? I guess it works but still...

Comment: I understand maybe it's not the best solution but what I mean is that toFixed function rounding the value, so Math.cos(90 deg) returns a result very close to zero by rounding it the result be zero but as a string so it can be parsed to number.

Comment: Another example (5.5559). toFixed(3) -> "5.556"

Comment: Congrats, its still less precise? You are literally losing precision by doing that…

Comment: The first time I faced this problem, I was coding a simple calculator, all I wanted is to print the correct answer, So I just shared my experience and if this solution is not suitable for your situation just ignore it.

Comment: In your opinion, what is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Maybe, but it’s not a solution, its a hack and it doesn’t address the issue at all, it just works around it. As a learning platform, I feel this doesn’t answer the question. But I have not downvoted it, so take this as constructive criticism.

Comment: Good solution? Don’t require JS for precision Math. Basically the accepted answer (the system works!) even with your system you can still run into the same rounding errors. So you moved to problem to snother unknown area.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a bug, and not even a rounding error from `Math.sin` itself.

Mathematics says `sin(π) = 0`. but `Math.PI` is only an approximation of π, so, mathematically, `sin(Math.PI)` is *not* zero. The value is also pretty clearly not a denormal, so it's not unexpected to get a non-zero value.

In fact, as the derivative of sin near π is around -1, we can estimate that `sin(x) ≈ π - x` (this is effectively an iteration of Newton's method). Substituting `Math.PI`, we obtain `π ≈ Math.PI + sin(Math.PI) ≈ Math.PI + Math.sin(Math.PI)`.

Indeed:

```
> Math.PI.toString(16)
'3.243f6a8885a3'
> Math.sin(Math.PI).toString(16)
'0.00000000000008d313198a2e038'
```

(I'm using hexadecimal because floats aren't precisely formatted when using decimal)

The sum of these two numbers when computed by hand is 3.243f6a8885a308d313198a2e038, or, converted to decimal, 3.14159265358979323846264338327950587... This approximation of π is valid for 33 decimal digits, as opposed to the 17-digit approximation provided by `Math.PI` -- almost doubling the precision. Of course, you can't actually work with such a number in JS's builtin floats, but there are tricks such as double-double arithmetic.

Anyway: `Math.sin` is, in fact, extremely accurate -- it's `Math.PI` that introduces the error!