# Detect if a number is dividable by 100 in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, numbers, divide

I want to detect if a number is dividable by 100 in NodeJS. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript how to tell if one number is a multiple of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037926/javascript-how-to-tell-if-one-number-is-a-multiple-of-another)

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm asking for detecting a hundred, and not a multiple of another number, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: detecting a hundred is asking for a multiple of a hundred.

Comment: The answer and the fact that it was accepted confirm the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check reminder of the division by 100, if it is 0, then number ends with `00` like this:

```js
console.log(1 % 100 == 0); // false
console.log(100 % 100 == 0); // true
console.log(101 % 100 == 0); // false
console.log(200 % 100 == 0); // true
console.log(1000 % 100 == 0); // true
```