# How to use split function in jquery to split a value

Tags: jquery

I want to convert this php code snippet that converts/truncates a value:

here is the php code:

```
$currentcost = 42.35;
$currentcost = explode(".", $currentcost);

if($currentcost[1] <= 35) {
$currentcost[1] = 99;
$currentcost[0] -= 1;
}
echo $output = $currentcost[0] . "." . $currentcost[1];
```

This is supposed to be the condition:

**x.35** where x is any number. If the decimal number is less than or equal to 35 then convert the .35 into 99 and subtract the x value with 1.

Something like this:

42.35 will become 41.99

Comment: by the way, 8 questions and no accepts - why is that? no acceptable answers found yet ;)?

Comment: and what have you tried here so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to port it to Javascript as is (without the `%` optimization as shown in the other answer here), then have a look at the [array.split](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/javascript-php-explode-function-051018-1025/) method documentation. It should work like this:

```
var currentcost = 42.35;
var costpart = String(currentcost).split(".");
if (costpart[1] <= 35) {
    costpart[1] = 99;
    costpart[0] -= 1;
}
var output = costpart[0] + "." + costpart[1];
document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, it uses the modulo operator to get the decimal part of the number:

```
var currentcost = 42.35;

if ( (currentcost*100) % 100 <= 35) {
  currentcost = Math.floor(currentcost) - 0.01;
}

document.write(currentcost);
```

Edit: For an explanation on the way floating point values are handled here, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966484/floating-point-numbers-and-javascript-modulus-operator).

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work (see http://jsfiddle.net/L9ksC/); first, it should be `<=`, instead of `<`, and second, it seems the numerical accuracy in javascript prevents `42.35 % 1 <= 0.35` from being true...

Comment: the new solution is even worse - Math.ceil returns the nearest **integer**, meaning the part before % 1 in the if condition will always be 0 (which is smaller then 0.35), meaning it will always return *next smaller integer, with .99 after comma* ... and I think %1 doesn't work as you think it does (and not as I thought at first too).

Comment: @nyarlathotep: yeah that was wrong, I don't think I can get away from the floating point error, appart doing something silly like `<= 0.350000000014` or <= 0.36

Comment: true, floating point variables are always tricky ;). For ideas on how to get it work (would be a nicer solution after all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966484/floating-point-numbers-and-javascript-modulus-operator) Multiplying before modulo seems to do the trick, as you tried, but without the division and without Math.ceil...

Comment: actually < 0.36 make the trick if you are manipulating money ;-)

Comment: Yeah but that'll only work if you always only use 2 digits after the comma; values like 42.351 would also be handled. Check out my solution (see link in my last comment): multiplying by 100 before modulo... that way, it also works if there should be more than 2 digits after comma in the given value! I took the liberty of editing your answer, hope that's ok.