# Why 2.4 mod 0.8 returns 0.8

Tags: javascript, php, math

Why modulus calculation of 2.4 by 0.8 returns 0.8? Shouldn't it return 0?

It happens both in PHP, via `fmod`, and JavaScript, via `%`.

Even a google research with this operation fails: http://www.google.com/search?q=2.4+mod+0.8

Comment: it is even worse when i tried in chrome, it shows `0.7999999999999998`

Comment: you should really just multiply all numbers by 10 to the power of how many decimals you have

Comment: It is because of how floating point numbers are represented in memory…
btw `0.8*3 = 2.4000000000000004`
see website http://0.30000000000000004.com for more details on this

Comment: @RiggsFolly Plus, the linked question is about C and C++, not PHP.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think language matters all too much (after all, OP is also asking about JavaScript). This seems to be about floating point math in combination with fmod in general, I guess? Ah, what do I know. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966484/why-does-modulus-operator-return-fractional-number-in-javascript

Comment: @idmean Before we wrongly flag this as duplicate a second time, does that really answer why an expected result of `0.0` turns out as `0.8` or `0.7999999999999998`? I think a more in-depth explanation (example of the steps involved) might actually be warranted here? Not sure.

Comment: @domsson I think the 2nd answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/3966533/1779477 does answer the question. Reading that I could exactly relieve where the rounding error occurs.

Comment: `bc` correctly returns 0 `bc -l <<< '2.4%0.8'`

Comment: Also tested in Python3 `>>> 2.4%0.8` returns `0.7999999999999998`, and `>>> import decimal as d >>> d.Decimal(2.4)%dDecimal(0.8)` returns `d.Decimal('0.7999999999999998223643160600')`, interestingly, `>>> d.Decimal('2.4')%dDecimal('0.8')` returns `Decimal('0.0')`. Note the `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closer at what happens in this concrete example, the influence of the binary format becomes more visible.

The input is stored as a binary floating point approximation. This then can be printed as decimal number uniquely identifying the binary,

```
In [1]: print "%.25f"%2.4
2.3999999999999999111821580

In [2]: print "%.25f"%0.8
0.8000000000000000444089210
```

The first step is the computation of the quotient and of its integer part. Obviously, as the stored numbers are smaller `2.4` and larger `0.8`, the quotient is smaller than `3`,

```
In [3]: print "%.25f"%(2.4/0.8)
2.9999999999999995559107901
```

The modulo result, the remainder, is then finally the difference after removing the integer multiple,

```
In [4]: print "%.25f"%(2.4-2*0.8)
0.7999999999999998223643161
```

Comment: That explains the `0.79999...` we see with some languages, but how does the `0.0` (!) come about that we see with, for example, PHP's `fmod()`?

Comment: This would depend on the algorithm used, for instance a different rounding mode for the quotient might give the more correct `3`. However, if the data type is standard double, then the `0.0` should actually be `-0.0000000000000004440892099`, which is negative and might violate remainder conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, in order to represent a number in decimal we do something like this:

```
1550 = 1000 + 5·100 + 5·10 = 1·10³ + 5·10² + 5·10¹
```

In order to represent a number in binary form from decimal you have to change bases:

```
106 = 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^3 + 2^1 = 0110 1010
```

Where 0's would equal to 0·2^7, 0·2^4, etc.

As you can see the pattern is clear: just sum powers of 2 as needed until you get the number you want until you reach 0 (2^0) for the number 1. If you take things a bit further it works the same for decimals, you just keep substracting 1 from the powers:

```
0.5 = 2^-1 = 1/2^1
```

Now for other numbers:

```
0.6875 = 0.1011 = 1/2^1 + 1/2^3 + 1/2^4
```

However, there are numbers that you can't represent as sums of inverse powers of two, something as simple as `0.1` should require you to add very small numbers to approach that value and would look like `0.0001100110011...` which actually rounds up to `0.0999755859375...`, and since the language has to change bases everytime you have to do arithmetics, these problems start to show up.