# Which objective-c type is appropriate for handling money?

Tags: objective-c, types, currency

Which objective-c type is appropriate for handling money? I need something which is Core Data compatible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two solutions:

- Use an `int`, and always keep track of monetary values in cents (or the smallest possible division of whatever currency you're using).  Use only integer calculations.
- Use [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which does exact decimal arithmetic.

Solution #1 requires you to convert between cents and dollars whenever you do input or output of monetary values, whereas solution #2 can be messier to code (e.g. you have to write something like `[num1 decimalNumberByAdding:num2]` instead of `num1 + num2` to add two numbers).

I'd recommend solution #1, but go with whichever of those you think would work best.

Comment: +1 - Also, for a thorough understanding of why *not* to use a floating point type, see David Goldberg's classic "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic": <http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html>

Comment: Also see this SO question: [Use float or decimal for accounting application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount)

Comment: Sorry - surrounding it with <>s works everywhere else... :-(  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html