# What is special about this math?

Tags: java, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/java-floating-point-arithmetic)

What is special about this double math in Java?  I would expect the answer of .9 - 1 to be -0.1, however the response is -0.09999999999999998

```
double a = 0.9;
double b = 1.0;
double c = a - b;
System.out.println(c);
>>-0.09999999999999998
```

Comment: Mandatory read : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: The float questions will never end!!!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point precision is difficult for computers. See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/) and [Retain precision with double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java) for details

For accurate floating point arithmetic use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another question about precision of doubles. 
Doubles have limited precision. Not all numbers can be represented precisely!

Answer (score 1):

The value 0.9 cannot be represented exactly in binary form.

Answer (score 1):

double is not exact. this is the nearest number that can be represented by double.

try to read [what every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of numbers between any two values.

There are a finite number of memory bits on any computer. So any way we chose to represent floating point numbers will never be exact.

Comment: actually, even if there were infinite but countable memory, it still won't be enough, since there are uncountable number of elements between each two numbers. [so any turing machine will never be able to precisely represent a real number]