# Convert a VARCHAR(n) to exact FLOAT

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, accounting

I have an accounting application. In my application, users can determine the number of decimal number, so I can't use `decimal` data type because it has fixed precision and scale.

According this topic,
[Use Float or Decimal for Accounting Application Dollar Amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount), never use float because it's just an approximation.
So instead I use `VARCHAR(n)` as the data type for my column.

Now ,I want use `SUM` function on this column and I want the exact value of column. How can I do it?

Comment: Check the convert method, you can do something like: convert(float, yourVarcharColumn), maybe it will give you a start.

Comment: if I convert to float is value is exact?

Comment: please read the question i want convert VARCHAR to float and he want convert float to  VARCHAR

Comment: You are right, I added the wrong URL: http://raresql.com/2013/04/26/sql-server-how-to-convert-varchar-to-float/

Comment: You could use the CLR and load the values to sum into a BigRational implementation. (Or write it yourself. Summing decimals in strings isn't too difficult)

Comment: SQL Server supports maximum precision and scale 38 for [`decimal type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). If your numbers can have more than 38 significant digits, then the built-in `SUM` can't be used without the loss of precision. Overall, this requirement looks strange to me. Usually in accounting it is known how many decimal places should be used. At least, usually it is known how many decimal places should be reserved. And usually it is 2 or 4. That's why there is a type called [`money`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have sum on `CHAR` data type in a normal way. You need to `CONVERT` it to a number and then do the calculations.

My suggestion is to go for `DECIMAL` and if the end user can change the number of precision and scale, consider the maximum possible you can have and have SQL Server make the other digits as 0

For example if you choose `DECIMAL(19, 4)` and end user selects to have just 2 scale, SQL Server make the other two digits as 0

```
CREATE TABLE test(mny DECIMAL(18, 4))
INSERT INTO test VALUES (239428394.87)

SELECT * FROM test


OUTPUT
-----------------
239428394.8700
```

Also you have an option to use `MONEY` data type.

[Comparing MONEY and DECIMAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

If you want to use `CHAR`, try this:

```
DECLARE @precision INT
        ,@scale INT
        ,@output VARCHAR(1000)
        ,@input CHAR(10) = '234234.453'

SELECT  @precision = LEN(LEFT(@input, CHARINDEX('.', @input) - 1)) + LEN(SUBSTRING(@input,CHARINDEX('.', @input) + 1, LEN(@input)))
        ,@scale = LEN(SUBSTRING(@input, CHARINDEX('.', @input) + 1, LEN(@input)))

SELECT @Output = 'SELECT SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @precision) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @scale) + '), ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @input) + '))'
SELECT @Output
EXEC (@Output)
```

You can dynamically get precision and scale of each number and make a dynamic query

Comment: thanks for your answer I know i cannot have sum on CHAR but i want some casting on my query.

Comment: You can `SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), value))` but I strongly recommend you to not to use CHAR

Comment: but maybe the scale bigger than 4. my problem is the scale is dynamic and user can determine scale now I don't know what should i do?

Comment: Make that DECIMAL(18, 4) to the max possible one

Comment: thanks for your Ideas . i use Entity framework and I don't think about a dynamic query .