# Getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis silly platform

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table bill_payment (
  billid varchar(5) primary key,
  pid varchar(5),
  amount float(7,2),
  constraint bill_payment_pid_fk foreign key(pid) references patient_master(pid) 
);
```

Comment: float(7,2)? Is that a valid Oracle data type? Try numeric(7,2).

Comment: `number(7,2)` * :)

Comment: What does "silly platform" mean in the title? Also: when you look at an error message, try to understand what it is telling you. Your error message shows the exact line and position where the error is found, in this case on the line defining "amount" and right after the 7. If you post this additional information it will be that much easier to get answers from this forum. In this case the problem was easy, but when you have 40 lines of code it will be more difficult. Show the full error message.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use an approximate data type (type `float`) instead of a precise one (type `number`) when you can avoid it (which you usually can). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount

Answer (score 1):

change `float(7,2)` to `float(2)`

In case of float, only value of precision is required.

You can use `Number(7,2)` also.

Comment: If it was helpful then you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be that complex. And unless you are developing for the zimbabwean dollar the "number" type should do the trick.

You should also make some extra fields for future reference.

```
create table bill_payment
(
   billid         varchar (5) primary key,
   pid            varchar (5)    references patient_master (pid),
   amount         number,
   payment_date   date
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
CREATE TABLE bill_payment 
  ( 
     billid VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
     pid    VARCHAR(5), 
     amount NUMBER(7, 2), 
     CONSTRAINT bill_payment_pid_fk FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES patient_master(pid) 
  );
```