# System.Data.SqlClient stores wrong data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, floating-point

I have a C# program pulling some data and put into SQL Server

```
public void UpdateElementInfo()
{
    var _db = new MyEntities();

    var mylist = _db.elements.Where(x => x.id != null);

    IList<ele> plist = mylist.ToList<ele>();

    foreach (ele p in plist)
    {
        var query = from myRow in dtrr.AsEnumerable()
                    where myRow.Field<string>("num") == p.id.ToString()
                    select myRow;
        var rrrr = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("updated_at")).FirstOrDefault();

        {
            p.my_interested_param = (double?)rrrr.Field<decimal?>("parameter") * 100;
```

So if I do `Console.WriteLine()` this my_interested_param, it shows as expected, 4.12 for example. However, when I looked in SQL Server, this number is actually converted into 4.1200000000000003. Moreover, this conversion does not happen to all of the rows. So it is very strange to me.

I read that this might be due to the `FLOAT` data type chosen to store this number. However, what we could do if we have to use `FLOAT` to store it.

Comment: That's what happens with floating points. Why do you use it if you don't want this behaviour?

Comment: I am using it because previous people used it. I do not want to touch the DB at this point, so I am thinking if there is solution on the C# coding level. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no solution. Floating points are not accurate numbers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!